# PHP MySql 000webhost retrieve data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to using database with php, using 000webhost I don't know what to write to get data from specific table

**connection.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****************";
$password = "***********";
$database = "*****************";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {    
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

**getalldata.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

//get data from Database

?>
```

Comment: See `php.net` about using the PDO functions. They also have basic example usage as well and apply what they show to your DB and table info. Also, you might find [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you are fetching records from studentrecord

`` require_once 'connection.php';
$roll = $_POST['roll'];  

$query = "SELECT * from studentrecord where roll = '$roll'";

try{
    $statement = $conn->query($query);

    echo "<table border='1'>    
          <tr>    
            <td>Roll</td>    
            <td>Stream</td>    
            <td>Session</td>    
            <td>Name</td>    
            <td>Mother Name</td>    
            <td>Father Name</td>    
            <td>Total Mark's</td>    
            <td>Grade</td>    
            <td>Result</td>    
          </tr>"; 

    //if you want to fetch records as an array indexed 
    while ($result = $statement->fetch()){
      echo "<tr>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['id'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['stream'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['session'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['name'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['mother_name'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['father_name'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['total_marks'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['grade'] . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result['result'] . "</td>";     
      echo "</tr>";  
    }

    //if you want to fetch records as an anonymous object 
    while ($result = $statement->fetchObject()){
      echo "<tr>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->id . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->stream . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->session . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->name . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->mother_name . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->father_name . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->total_marks . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->grade . "</td>";     
      echo "<td>" . $result->result . "</td>";     
      echo "</tr>";  
    }


    echo "</table>";  

} 
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Failed to retrieve record".$ex->getMessage();
`enter code here`} ``